# Conditional intializations of parameters in hydra

Tags: yaml, fb-hydra, omegaconf

I'm pretty new to hydra and was wondering if the following thing is was possible: I have the parameter `num_atom_feats` in the `model` section which I would like to make dependent on the `feat_type` parameter in the `data` section. In particular, if I have `feat_type: type1` then I would like to have `num_atom_feats:22`. If instead, I initialize `data` with `feat_type : type2` then I would like to have `num_atom_feats:200`

```yaml
model:
  _target_: model.EmbNet_Lightning
  model_name: 'EmbNet'
  num_atom_feats: 22
  dim_target: 128
  loss: 'log_ratio'
  lr: 1e-3
  wd: 5e-6

data:
  _target_: data.DataModule
  feat_type: 'type1'
  batch_size: 64
  data_path: '.'

wandb:
  _target_:  pytorch_lightning.loggers.WandbLogger
  name: embnet_logger
  project: ''

trainer:
  max_epochs: 1000
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this using OmeagConf's [`custom resolver`](https://omegaconf.readthedocs.io/en/2.2_branch/custom_resolvers.html) feature.

Here's an example showing how to register a custom resolver that computes `model.num_atom_feat` based on the value of `data.feat_type`:

```py
from omegaconf import OmegaConf

yaml_data = """
model:
  _target_: model.EmbNet_Lightning
  model_name: 'EmbNet'
  num_atom_feats: ${compute_num_atom_feats:${data.feat_type}}

data:
  _target_: data.DataModule
  feat_type: 'type1'
"""

def compute_num_atom_feats(feat_type: str) -> int:
    if feat_type == "type1":
        return 22
    if feat_type == "type2":
        return 200
    assert False

OmegaConf.register_new_resolver("compute_num_atom_feats", compute_num_atom_feats)


cfg = OmegaConf.create(yaml_data)

assert cfg.data.feat_type == 'type1'
assert cfg.model.num_atom_feats == 22
cfg.data.feat_type = 'type2'
assert cfg.model.num_atom_feats == 200
```

I'd recommend reading through the docs of OmegaConf, which is the backend used by Hydra.

The `compute_num_atom_feats` function is invoked lazily when you access `cfg.data.num_atom_feats` in your python code.

When using custom resolvers with Hydra, you can call `OmegaConf.register_new_resolver` either before you invoke your `@hydra.main`-decorated function, or from within the `@hydra.main`-decorated function itself. The important thing is that you call `OmegaConf.register_new_resolver` before you access `cfg.data.num_atom_feats`.